# What does "developed in the wake of the XX" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

The sentence I am having the confusion in is this-

"The X kingdom and others (Y, Z), led by chieftains of indigenous tribes, developed in the wake of the A kingdom, were examples of indigenous state formations in Medieval B."

Comment: This is from a Wikipedia article, so I am mostly certain there is no grammatical error here.

Comment: That is not a great assumption about Wikipedia articles in general.

Comment: In this particular case, the clause with "wake" is fine, but the rest of the sentence [from this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kachari_Kingdom&oldid=811933437) is a hot mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Wake" in this context is the disturbance in water after a boat has passed (which lasts a while but not too long).

This is saying, metaphorically, that they could not have come along without the influence of the first society and followed after the first one fell.